# Webbrowser, прогрузка новой страницы

Tags: c#

На форме есть webbrowser и кнопка "далее", а так же файл с набором ссылок, имеющий вид:

```
ссылка1
ссылка2
ссылка3
...
```

как сделать, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку открывалась новая ссылка? т.е. нажал кнопку далее, открылась 1-ая ссылка, ещё раз нажал, открылась 2-ая и т.д. ?

Comment: А причем здесь webbrowser? Почему этого нельзя сделать на Java Script в самом файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш класс формы может выглядеть примерно так:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Stack<string> linkStack;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var links = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\links.txt");
        linkStack = new Stack<string>(links);   
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (linkStack.Count > 0)
        {
            var link = linkStack.Pop();
            webBrowser1.Navigate(link);
        }
    }   
}
```

Нужно сделать привязку события нажатия на кнопку к вызову метода `button1_Click`.